# Basic Website Web Form - How to link DropDownList to internal .aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdownlistfor, .aspxauth

I'm relatively new to using VB, and am trying to do the following:

1. Select DropDownList item upon Button click
2. Link DropDownList items to internal pages

I feel like this is basic stuff, but am having a hard time with it.

Is this correct?

1 .

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Value="Answer.aspx">Answer</asp:ListItem>
```

2 .

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />`
```

Comment: "Link DropDownList items to internal pages" - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: onselectedindexchanged is not a property of Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your code a little bit to achieve this.  First, you do not need the AutoPostback on the dropdown list unless you want it to hit the server when you select a new list item.

On the button click, you will want to remove the

```
OnSelectedIndexChange="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

And replace it instead with the button's OnClick event.

```
OnClick = "Button1_Click"
```

You will need to add your vb code to redirect to the new page.  I'm more of a C# guy, but this should work.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim LinkText as string
    LinkText = DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Value
    Response.Redirect(LinkText)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say, after clicking the button, it will go to the other page by selecting in dropdownlist what page it is? If I'm correct, here's how it is.

```
    Private Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
          Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString)
    End Sub
```